# avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding When installing GRBL

Tags: windows, arduino, avrdude

I am trying to install GRBL onto my Arduino Uno without any luck. Every time I try to upload it, I keep getting the same error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NULye.png

As you can see, I have it set to the correct board and port. I can also write any of the examples to the board without any issues, and have also tried a few other cables just for good measure. I did a loopback test on it, and it passed without any issues.

Why can I not upload grbl?

Running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit
Using latest IDE

Comment: So you can upload any Arduino example but no luck wit grbl?

Comment: A little update, a pulled out my brother's Duemilanove, and it uploaded to that perfectly. This makes me want to think it is my Uno. HOWEVER, I can upload any other example sketch and it works perfectly fine! Did blink, a motor driver, some other stuff, it all works! Uploading is fine, and if I attach hardware, it works as it should. But it doesn't take the GRBL. The same GRBL program uploads perfectly fine to the Duemilanove though...

Comment: About attaching hardware... Did you try to program it without anything attached? I mean no shields and no more hw, just the arduino UNO and the USB cable..

Comment: Yup. Tried with, without, everything.

Comment: This is really strange... I never experienced something like this... Can you try on other UNOs?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any other unos on hand. However, I may buy one to dedicate to the CNC machine it would be used for. That won't be for a few weeks (or until I get everything working working with the current arduino)

Comment: same error on linux, both the IDE and avrdude hang at 94%. Any other sketch upload fine.

Answer (score 0):

What about directly flashing a pre-build hex file?

Just download this file: https://github.com/grbl/grbl-builds/blob/master/builds/grbl_v0_9j_atmega328p_16mhz_115200_for_SO2.hex
(If you don't have git, just copy the complete code make a new .txt file, paste the code and "save as": grbl_v0_9j_atmega328p_16mhz_115200_for_SO2.hex)
And then the uploader (xloader, you may have heard about that): http://xloader.russemotto.com/
Open xloader and navigate to your hex file you've just downloaded.
Select your device from the dropdown (Arduino UNO, 328) and set the baud rate to 115200. 
Select the COM-Port you've attacehd your Uno to (you can take a look at the device manager and search for your COM-Port).
Now just hit upload, but double check the baud rate 115200 for UNO).

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an Arduino UNO and version 1.1 of GRBL - turns out I overwrote the bootloader (or part of it) while uploading GRBL because the build was larger than 30KB, and while the Arduino UNO ATMega328p has 32KB of program memory, the last 2KB are reserved for a bootloader.

Arduino IDE version 1.5.3 [produced 31,892 byte file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecCks.png) (too big).  Upgrading to Arduino IDE version 1.8.5 and rebuilding produced a [30,562 byte file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhlnc.png), which fits (just barely!  30KB is 30,720 bytes).

I reflashed the ATMega328p bootloader directly using the SPI programming interface and an external programmer, using the prebuilt [.hex file Arduino bootloader for the ATMega328p from Github](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/atmega).  You'll want the one called "ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328_pro_8MHz.hex".  Just go to "View Raw" on Github and save the page as a .hex file.

Alternatively, [this Sparkfun page](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader) explains how to make an extra Arduino (Duemilanove or Uno) into an ISP programmer, and how to reflash the bootloader using the extra Arduino as an ISP (Tools->Burn Bootloader).

With the bootloader reprogrammed and GRBL built to be less than 30KB, you should have no problem uploading the sketch.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a v3.3 firmware on the Arduino Uno board. Updating the bootloader to the latest version (v4.4 in my case) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same symptoms as the question asker, the Uno was able to accept other sketches like blink LED without an issue, but not the GRBL sketch. My solution was to chose the "AVR ISP" as the programmer instead of the "AVRISP mk2", which was the default option. I hope this might help someone in the future.